# jQuery toggleClass on accordion issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So have this small HTML, JS and CSS for a small accordion im making which uses font-awesome icons.

By default we have the first accordion panel open and have the icon "fa-minus" and the others are closed with "fa-plus" now the toggle i added changes the icon on which ever you click but of course need to reset the default and change them to the correct icons as you go through the accordion. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('.open').parent().removeClass('fa-minus');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".panel-collapse").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel-heading .status {
  float: right;
}
.panel-collapse {
  display: none;
}
.panel-collapse.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">testing 1<i class="status fa fa-minus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse open">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="featureTitle2">test 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="featureTitle2" placeholder="Title..." value="<?php echo $featureTitle2 ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">test 2<i class="status fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">test 3<i class="status fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a callback that gets fired when the `.slideToggle()`/`.slideUp()` methods finish.

In the callback, you can check whether the accordion is hidden, and then add the corresponding class to the icon:

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(iconCallback);
  $(".panel-collapse").not($(this).next()).slideUp(iconCallback);

  function iconCallback() {
    var iconClass = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus';
    $(this).prev().find('i').removeClass('fa-plus fa-minus').addClass(iconClass);
  }
});
```

Updated Example:

```js
$('#accordion .panel-heading').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(iconCallback);
  $(".panel-collapse").not($(this).next()).slideUp(iconCallback);

  function iconCallback() {
    var iconClass = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus';
    $(this).prev().find('i').removeClass('fa-plus fa-minus').addClass(iconClass);
  }
});
```

```css
.panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel-heading .status {
  float: right;
}
.panel-collapse {
  display: none;
}
.panel-collapse.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">testing 1<i class="status fa fa-minus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse open">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="featureTitle2">test 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="featureTitle2" placeholder="Title..." value="<?php echo $featureTitle2 ?>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">test 2<i class="status fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">test 3<i class="status fa fa-plus"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```